# Makefile link math.h

Tags: makefile

I try to add LDLIBS=-lm  to my makefile, to link math.h, but I get the same error as before "sin undeclared " function. Here is part of my makefile:

I appreciate your help in advance.

```
LDLIBS=-lm

 ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4  

     bin_PROGRAMS = \
kdv

    kdv_SOURCES = kdv.c vector.c 


    lib_LIBRARIES = liblinalg.a
    liblinalg_a_SOURCES = \
kdv.h \
vector.c 


     LDADD = liblinalg.a 

     TESTS = \
kdv
```

Comment: This looks like an automake file, not a makefile.  Are you running automake then make?  Or just make alone?

Comment: You are right. I am running automake. Do I need to add LDLIBS=-lm to may configure.ac file?

Comment: Problem is solved. changed my configure.ac.